# SignalR in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, signalr, game-development, real-time-multiplayer

I am new to signalR and I want to know that is there any way to use signalR Core in unity3d? Because I am developing a multiplayer unity game and need a real-time response from a web api. So, does anybody know about that?

Comment: This tutorial may help: https://damienbod.com/2013/11/05/using-signalr-with-unity/

Comment: @SanketPrabhu Thank you so much, but I need a sample for SignalR Core implementation in unity3d because I'm working with a web api.

Comment: Had any luck with this? Trying to implement the same.

Comment: @SimonRaes Not really. I’m using photon unity networking now. It is far easier than the signals.